# .htaccess how to show "index.php" in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello i create a little cms to learn mvc and i have a very basic problem.

normally the whole url after my domain would shown in a variable but if i type the word "index" my variable is totally empty.

my index.php:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url];

echo $url;

?>
```

that's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so if i type the following urls:

"localhost/~username/mycms/indexabc" result => indexabc

"localhost/~username/mycms/index" result =>

"localhost/~username/mycms/index.php" result =>

"localhost/~username/mycms/index.php2" result => index.php2

anyone an idea what should i do that my .htaccess also redirect the index and index.php?

my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/Users/Sam/Sites/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule is applied only if those conditions are applied:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Conditions means that they'll be applied only if your URL is not existing directory, file, or filesystem link. I'm sure that file index.php exists, so this is the reason why `localhost/~username/mycms/index.php` does not work.

I think that there is also existing file or directory with name `index` inside `mycms` directory. This can be the reason why `localhost/~username/mycms/index` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial but on my localhost it doesn't work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM&t=1191s

I have a `index.php` in my folder, but not a folder.

That confuses me, because I do not understand what's wrong on my localhost.